# How to get the right offset after CSS3 transform scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform, scale

I'm trying to do this grid of images. If I click one of them, I want to scale everything and focus on the one I just clicked.

Here is the testing code: http://jsfiddle.net/7PzGQ/7/

Thanks!

Comment: Tried to play with it, can't figure it out.. But, you can get the offset of the clicked image with `$( this ).offset().top` or `$( this ).offset().left`

Comment: Yeah, I was playing with that, but I've no idea what math will do what I want to do. I suck at this.

Answer (score 2):

Simple math probleme, check out this :
http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/7PzGQ/87/